# Create one presentation out of several presentations?

Tags: beamer, include

Is there a way to combine several Beamer presentations into one big presentation?

E.G.: If I have two files a.tex and b.tex which are both presentations, can I compile them into one big presentation?

Comment: Perhaps with [`combine`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/combine) or with [`pdfpages`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfpages)

Answer (score 6):

An example with `docmute`:

> a.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test A}
This is A 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> b.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test B}
This is B
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> bigpresentation.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Big presentation}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
\input{a}
\input{b}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

One similar alternative is the `standalone` package.