# Splitting a document per chapter with preample for Latexian live preview

Tags: chapters, preamble, latexian

Currently, I have my main LaTeX document set up as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\title{Mytitle} \author{Me} \date{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/chapter01}
\end{document}
```

While my chapters themselves contain no preamble, no begin/end document etc, just the contents of the chapter itself.

I use Latexian and really enjoy the live preview function in a split screen. I would like to write each individual chapter and use the live preview feature, however, I cannot compile/preview each chapter on its own without its own preamble, begin/end document etc.

Is there a way around this? It feels very clunky to have to switch back and forth between a window containing just my chapter and one containing the entire thesis. Similarly, it feels very clunky to have each chapter contain everything necessary to compile and then manually comment out the extra lines from every single chapter when I wish to compile them all together.

Comment: Doesn't Latexian allow you to set a master document or main file or similar? Many editors have a concept of a project so that compiling any file in that project can be configured to compile the main/master file. If you use `\include` rather than `\input`, you can use `\includeonly{}`as mentioned below. Alternatively, look at `standalone` or `import` for other possibilities.

Comment: @cfr I have never heard of this feature before, but it looks like what I am after. I will have to see whether or not Latexian can do this, thank you.

Comment: @cfr The feature was fairly well hidden, but that completely solved my issue.

Comment: You should put te `\chapter{<title>}` command within te chapter file.

Comment: look into the `subfiles` package.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your chapters in complete documents (with the same preample that the main document) and then go to [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org) to known about the topic [subdoc: in­clude com­plete doc­u­ments in other doc­u­ments](https://www.ctan.org/topic/subdocs). In particular, `docmute` or `standalone` packages is what your are looking for. It is a simple as add one of these packages to the preamble of the main document  (there are many examples of use of both packages in this site, for example [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136727/11604).

I suggest also move  rest of the preamble to a `preamble.tex` file and left in the main document only `\input{preamble}` and use only this command in the preambles of the child fles, because if you need change some change in the preambles, you only have to do once, avoiding mistakes.

Alternatively, as suggested in the other answer, you can also preview the main document with only a chapter, using  `\includeonly{...}` in the preamble of the main document, but note that this command affect to `\include` commands, not to `\input` (see [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include)), so in your example, you should  change `\chapter{...}\input{...}` by only  `\include{...}` with `\chapter{...}` included in the child document.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have a `compile01.tex` file which contains:

```
\documentclass{thesis_template}
\usepackage{../my_preamble}% all your package loads and custom macros in one file. (You could also \input it)
\begin{document}
\input{chapter01}
\end{document}
```

You'd then have `compile02.tex` etc. as well.  I didn't use this approach for chapters (I wanted to test the bibliography and TOC often enough that it wasn't worth it, instead I preferred to use `\includeonly` or comment out the `\include`/`\input`lines in my `thesis_master.tex`  ). But I did set up something similar for TikZ pictures to avoid compiling the whole thesis while fine-tuning a figure.

Comment: Although your suggestion will not produce the same result that `\includeonly` in `main.tex` and simplify check  partial results,  basically translate the hassle of having to compile `main.tex` to the hassle of of compile through a third file for each chapter,  but the main point of the question is see a live preview while editing `chapter01.tex`,  that is not really solved in this way

Comment: @Fran I don't use Latexian so it wasn't obvious to me that this wouldn't generate a live preview until you said so.  My thesis files were big enough that for all but the introduction, compilation of a single chapter took a few tens of seconds on a fast machine.  With frequent saving it would be almost constantly updating.  So I compiled on my own schedule

Answer (score -1):

Plenty of other questions on this same topic. I think the easiest way to do it is to put a line like this in your preamble:

```
\includeonly{chapter2}
```

[Typeset single chapter from book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/typeset-single-chapter-from-book)

Edit: And use \include instead of \input

Comment: This really doesn't address the question and adding this to the preamble in the question will just produce an error.

Comment: @cfr not sure I understand your comment. Because you also posted above: "If you use \include rather than \input, you can use \includeonly{}as mentioned below." Why post the same advice as me and downvote my brief response plus link to information? Is it because you thought I should copy more of their answer?

Comment: @TomAnderson I think the problem is that the code in the question doesn't have any chapters, so more is needed than just adding `\includeonly`: the source also needs to be set up correctly.

Comment: The source in the question doesn't use `\include{}`. You can't use `\includeonly{}` with `\input{}`.

Comment: By the way, it was not me who down-voted your answer. @JosephWright ??

Comment: @cfr Doesn't really matter about the downvote, i was just wondering about the cryptic response. The link illustrates how to do it with \includeonly{}