# Skipping some lines when using `input` or `include`

Tags: input, include

I  would like to know if it is possible to use `input` or `include` skipping some lines in the imported source.

Comment: Not by default, but there could be some work arounds.  Could you more fully explain what you want to do?

Comment: I have separate files with my lessons created with the `beamer` package and I would like to create a new unique file, in the article mode using `beamerarticle` package, that should include all the lecture material. In this way, it would be more convenient for my students to print all the material.

Comment: `input` and `include` act as if the lines of the argument were written in the master tex file (with some other steps that doesn't concern us at the moment).  The point of `beamerarticle` is to have some lines that get skipped when in particular modes.  So the answer to your question is "no, input and include can't skip lines".  On the other hand, "yes, beamerarticle can skip lines".

Comment: Ok. Thank you. And can one decide which lines to skip with beamerarticle? If so, I could merge two or more documents into a single one.

Comment: Perhaps, I realize I just need to use a package like `docmute`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135518/create-one-presentation-out-of-several-presentations

Comment: Or subfiles, or standalone.  But that would only be necessary if you were trying to input or include one complete tex file into another complete tex file.  Which is entirely possible, but should have been mentioned as part of a minimal working example in your original question.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497