# Compiling one file

Tags: overleaf, include, files

We are collaborating on a project, each member is responsible for a topic.

[image]

The file structure is like this. Aiac-paper is the main file, and I added every file with `\include{...}`. My question is, is something like that possible? I compile only Abstract.tex another one compiles only Data.tex. There are lots of text which is not my business, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you mean by "I compile only Abstract.tex another one compiles only Data.tex".  Usually, the only thing compiling is the main file.  If that has `\include{Abstract}`, then it will do so.  If you want to be able to compile `Abstract.tex` on its own, you can try the subfiles package, but I don't know how well that will work with Overleaf.

Comment: I just want this, for example, we have 2 files, a.tex, and b.tex. I only want to see the preview of a.tex, and another person wants to see b.tex, but still, there will be a main.tex file that includes a.tex and b.tex

Comment: if you use `\include` you are always making the pdf of the main document not your chapter

Comment: For example in a python workspace, there is also a main file that can include other files, but I can also run a file which is not main

Comment: Try the subfiles package: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_subfiles_package

Comment: See [this simple example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136727/11604). It is  for a beamer presentation, but  the strategy is exactly the same for another document classes. The `docmute` package simply ignore the preambles of the subdocuments. Therefore the contents of every part must be compatible with the main preamble, but the subdocuments could have even different formats (margins,  etc.) for the part previews.